# Websphere 7 classloading delegation

Tags: dependencies, websphere, apache-axis, classloader

Hi I'm trying to make axis2 work on Websphere 7, I did the sugested configuration in the apache axis site (changing the axis2.xml "EnableChildFirstClassLoading" parameter and change the classloader from "PARENT_FIST" to "PARENT_LAST" for the webmodule that contains axis2)

However inside the same EAR there is another web application with JSP and struts that after changing the classloader stops working (due to jar libraries version problems), my deployment.xml looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appdeployment:Deployment xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi" xmi:id="Deployment_1335990730424">
<deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" xmi:id="ApplicationDeployment_1335990730424" startingWeight="10">
<modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1335990730424" startingWeight="10000" uri="StrutsWeb.war"/>
<modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1335990730425" startingWeight="10000" uri="Axis2Web.war" classloaderMode="PARENT_LAST"/>
<classloader xmi:id="Classloader_1335990730424" mode="PARENT_FIRST"/>
</deployedObject>
</appdeployment:Deployment>
```

Once I remove the "PARENT_LAST" from the axis2 web module the struts module starts working, with "PARENT_LAST" the web service works perfect but the struts web module doesn't. Seems like the classloader mode change is affecting both Web Modules.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere Application Server (like almost all application servers), there is a hierarchy of class loaders:

```
Application server class loaders
|   Includes WAS_HOME/plugins, WAS_HOME/lib, etc.
|
+-- Application class loader
    |   Includes files in lib/ folder of the .ear
    |   Includes all JARs referenced from Class-Path in all .war
    |
    +-- StrutsWeb.war class loader
    |      Includes WEB-INF/classes and all JARs in WEB-INF/lib
    |
    +-- Axis2Web.war
           Includes WEB-INF/classes and all JARs in WEB-INF/lib
```

The `<classloader>` element in your config snippet is nested within `ApplicationDeployment`, so it corresponds to the application class loader.  You probably don't want to modify this element, you probably want to modify the delegation mode of the individual WAR modules.  However, if changing this setting is having an effect, then you probably have JARs on the application class loader class path that should actually be within the WEB-INF/lib of your WAR modules.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, what I'm trying to do is to override the axis implementation bundled with websphere, I have all the required libraries on WEB-INF/lib and PARENT_LAST is fine to ignore the server implementation, however changing that delegation mode make the other web modules fail.

Comment: I cannot explain why changing the delegation mode of one WAR would affect any other.  I very much suspect this is a misconfiguration or mispackaging of some kind, but I can't guess what.  It might be easiest to open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I checked the application class loader and is configured as Multiple and not Single that could be a cause of this behavior, I think I'm going to switch from Axis to JAX-RPC.

Comment: I considered that, but the `ApplicationDeployment` in your config snippet does not show `warClassLoaderPolicy="SINGLE"`.  Anyway, that is certainly the reason why adjusting the mode affects both modules: using a single class loader policy means all modules in the application share a single class loader.